# Why does a UMN lesion cause hyper-reflexia?

Tags: neurology, nerves, reflex-impulse

I can see from my reading that "A lesion in an Upper Motor Neuron (UMN) causes Hyper-reflexia (with regards to the Golgi Tendon Reflex)".

I have read various resources but none of them give me a clear enough explanation to explain WHY this is the case.

One resource I read mentioned that the reticulospinal tracts (which receive impulses from UMNs that synapse at the reticular formation) inhibit all Lower Motor Neurons (including gamma motor neurons) & thus, a UMN lesion leads to gamma motor neuron activity rising & thereby increasing the muscle spindle's sensitivity to mechanical stimuli (eventually causing hyper-reflexia).

But then, other resources say that the reticulospinal tracts are responsible for stimulating flexion/extension, with no mention of inhibition of LMNs.

Comment: `I can see from my reading that...` -- What are you reading and who are you quoting? And what are the "other sources" you refer to? And finally, I'm assuming that UMN means upper-motor neurons and LMN means lower-motor neurons, but the standard in scientific writing is to spell-out your terms on first use and then provide the acronym after in parentheses. Please follow that standard here.

Comment: I'd also ask for a source. Basically, the so-called "deep tendon reflex" (the thing with the hammer) is not really about the Golgi tendon reflex as such. Actually, this reflex in particular seems to inhibit less when UMN lesions occurr, if anything.